# How to disable easing in skrollr plugin?

Tags: jquery, scroll, parallax, easing, skrollr

I'm using this plugin in a project for Parallax scrolling:
https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr

I found out how to change the easing, but somehow I cant figure out how to disable the easing completely.

Comment: I don't think you understand what the easing functions do. The term "disabling" is not applicable in this context.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are referring to the **smoothScrolling** option. I came here looking for an answer to this very question (and found none), so if we are both referring to the same effect, here is what you should do:

```
skrollr.init({smoothScrolling: false});
```